# "Command node not found" error with Bluemix Secure Gateway service

Tags: linux, ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

I am trying to start the Secure Gateway service for IBM Bluemix. The Linux box / command I am using is `node lib/secgwclient.js iuE3uds8dDB_prod_ng`. It results in:

> command node not found

I have installed the Secure Gateway / trying to install it.

Answer (score 1):

Please install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) on your Linux box before starting Secure Gateway client.  Thank you!